# Is there a way to change some "special" GUI colors in eclipse?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, eclipse-mars

I have on Linux/KDE a installed version of eclipse Mars.2. But there are strong problems with colors. So there is no different between a activated toolbar button and a inactive toolbar button. At example the "Link with editor" button of the "Project Explorer" view has exactly the same background color if the button is selected or not:

[image]

Another thing is that I cannot see if a checkbox or radio button is selected or not. It seems that the foreground color for the check/radio box selections is also identical to the background color. So there is in many configuration views no way to find out what's currently selected and wath's not. In the next screenshot at least one of the "Open mode" radio button must be selected (I assume it's "Double click" button):

[image]

Note also that the colors are only in eclipse wrong. In other (native) KDE applications I don't have these effects (at example the foreground of check boxes/radio buttons are black - like I have it expected). Also play around with the color settings in KDE "Application Appearance" has no effects ...

How can I change the colors of these stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the solution for my problem on following site:

http://www.jroller.com/andyl/entry/mars_on_linux

Mars is the first eclipse version which uses GTK3 (instead of GTK2 like eclipse versions before 4.5). And on the side above Andrey Loskutov wrotes that may be also the GTK theme (widget style) can be also the problem. The Widget style "oxygen-gtk" should be extremly buggy! After changing the widget style (to now "Adwaida") the problems are gone :-)

You can change the Widget style in KDE by opening in the KDE settings: "Application Appearance" and "GTK+ Appearance".

Answer (score 0):

There is an Eclipse plugin that helps you import downloaded themes from the online marketplace (themes are free).

This is where you can find it: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

You may choose whatever eclipse theme fits your needs!

Good luch!

Comment: Sure that a theme will change this kind of color? Have tried some different themes. Without success.